# Tick - no negative

Tags: chart.js

If I have a linear chart.js graph that often has all 0 values, it will show a high of 1 and a low of -1.  If I have values around 3000, I'll have a high and low around that value.  I want to specify no negatives - so I want the bottom value to be a minimum of 0.  There are options for min and suggestedMin, however, both these set the bottom value at 0.  So in the example of 3000, the top would be 3000 and the bottom would be 0, which is not what I want.  I want the 3000 to stay the same.  I just don't want it to show a -1 when the graph has 0s.  I want it to show a top of 1 and bottom of 0, similar to how the min works, but treat it like the minimum possible value, not actually setting the graph data low at that value. So in the case of 3000, 2997 might be the low.  But in the case of 0s, 0 is the low, not -1.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this as I only have a single dataset in each graph.  Happy to know if there is a better way.

```
function addData(chart, label, data) {
    chart.data.labels.push(label);
    chart.data.datasets.forEach((dataset) => {
        dataset.data.push(data);
        if (dataset.data.every(item => item === 0)) {
            chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = 0;
        } else {
            chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = undefined;
        }
    });
    chart.update();
}
```